# Need to style and display add event link in jqm calendar

Tags: jquery-mobile, calendar

I needed a calendar widget that would allow my users to select different dates and be shown any events happening on those dates. After a lot of searching (for simple solutions for a novice)  I finally came across this:

https://github.com/JWGmeligMeyling/jqm-calendar

It works excellently for what I need apart from two small problems that I spent the best part of 1.5 weeks trying to sort out.

I’m sincerely hoping that someone can help me. The first thing I really need it to do is this...

1. When any date is selected/highlighted, I would like an option to appear below the events list (if there are or aren't any) to say “Add event”. Ideally, the “Add event” option would be hyperlinked to a page of my choosing on my website. However, what I also need is for the link to pull in the date that the user has selected/highlighted. In other words the user can select any date in the calendar, click on the “Add event” link and then they will be redirected to a form on my page allowing them to create an event under the date they highlighted. So, the link would go something like : http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/add-event.asp?date=dd/mm/yyy

The second thing I need is more of a styling thing. I’m having trouble styling the following:

1. The section which displays the event list. I’m unable to select a different background or text colour.
2. When you select a date it turns blue. How can I select a different colour?

I have found very few examples of this calendar so I‘ve had few clues to go on

It’s coming up to two week I have been trying to solve this so any help at all would be so fully appreciated

Best regards

Rod from the UK